# Windows 7,8 and 10 Bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, boot, usb

I would like to know how to add applications to a Bootable usb so that when you boot from the usb it will install a standard set of application instead of having to install each application one at a time after you have installed Windows 7,8 and 10.

I have seen it done i would just like to try to cut down on install time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to just include installer to be run post-install using [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/features/), afterwards you can update the installer in the bootable usb with newer version directly. The cons is after OS installation you'll have to wait for the standard apps installation, and this only apply to apps that do have automated installation switch. If you also include the drivers for network card/wifi, you can even use [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) to always get the latest version.

A very involved method would be creating custom [WIM](http://finalthought.org/creating-customized-windows-8-1-media-iso-wim-flash-drive/). The OS along with whatever standard apps you include is installed on a single run. But preparing a new image require a dedicated clean install (on VM or just another partition).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use [YUMI MULTI-BOOT Application](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)  Which provides simplified information to make it easy for anyone to install, boot, and run their favorite Linux, Windows, etc.. Distro from a portable flash drive!